# Spotify Android Demo Project missing XML?

Tags: android, spotify, android-resources

I just downloaded the latest Beta 12 from
https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/releases

The sdk includes a file called "DemoActivity.js" but there is no corresponding XML for the resources, so this line of code fails to compile:
    `import com.spotify.sdk.embedded.demo.R;`

These refer to the various UI element objects such as

```
        R.id.skip_next_button,
        R.id.skip_prev_button,
        R.id.queue_song_button,
        R.id.toggle_shuffle_button,
        R.id.toggle_repeat_button
```

I have properly set my SDK references to the two aar files, so all of the other import references resolve properly, but not this one. Do we need to create our own XML for these or did they miss it? What am i missing?

Comment: This is still open on spotify as of now: https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/issues/210 and referred as a duplicate to this issue: https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/issues/269 -